# No free sectors available shown by fdisk in centos 7 minimal

Tags: partition, fdisk

This is the output of fdisk /dev/sdb

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk /dev/sdb
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 2
No free sectors available
```

This is the output of fdisk -l:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000d312d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    83886079    40893440   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcb3d9031

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     4194303     2096128   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 39.7 GB, 39720058880 bytes, 77578240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: sdb1 end sector is 4194303 ... sdb device has 4194304 sectors ... you've used all the sectors .... similar for sda ... you have no sectors free, exactly what is being reported to you

Comment: What's the solution? I deleted 2GB partition already and installed a new hard disk in that place.

Comment: you deleted a partition and installed a disk in its place? huh? anyway, the output of `fdisk -l` clearly shows your two disks are fully used for partitions, there's no room to make a new partition on either of them. There's zero evidence you deleted any partion anywhere

Comment: are you asking how to add that 2GB `/dev/sdb` to LVM perhaps?

Comment: yeah! I'm trying to set up LVM on my machine

Comment: looks like you already HAVE LVM on your machine */dev/sda2         2099200    83886079    40893440   8e  **Linux LVM*** - you want to make /dev/sdb1 a PV in the same VG as /dev/sda2, then you'll be able to add that 2GB to `centos-root` LV if you want - without any details about your PV's, VG's and LV's that's the best I can do